# Windows 7 machine shuts down without warning

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, power-options

I'm running into a problem that my PC shuts down without giving me any warnings.

I'm suspecting it's because my desktop PC's power plan settings is for a laptop. Both "balanced" and "power saver" are for laptops. How did that even happen?

t happens even if I just turned on the desktop. It prompts it's low in battery though it's a desktop... isn't that weird?

Any ideas on this?

Comment: It's most likely overheating.

Comment: It happens even if I just turned on the desktop. It prompts it's low in battery though it's a desktop... isn't that weird?

Comment: Possibly. How did you install it? There must be a reason it thinks it's a laptop. What happens if you disable the actions related to power saving? In other words, tell it to "Do Nothing" when it reaches assumed low or critical battery?

Comment: When you say "my PC shuts down" do you mean it executes a safe shutdown (you get the "Windows is Shutting down" screen), or that it just powers off with no warning?

Comment: powers off... poof! and that's it... T_T

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the icon in power management, in the control panel.  I agree that it's probably because the icon is visible.

Comment: When I go to power options and change plan settings, I have options for "On Battery" and "Plugged in" ... that's not suppose to happen right?

Comment: It looks like I read the title of your question instead of reading the question itself.  I suspect the computer shutting down is a driver failure or heat-related issue: logs might tell you more.

I doubt that the battery icon has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

If your com shutdown properly, then it is possible due to too high cpu temperature. you may download shareware cpu cool to check the cpu temp.

If it just turn off your com, then there should be some hardware problem. try to chang the power supply to see if the problem still persist.